# Invisible HTML Elements

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML file, the text contained in the inner divs such as "Argentina," or "Test Two" are not visible; I can't figure out why.  Any help on why they are invisible would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="GLH-2XVBBO">
        <div
            style="position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 190px; top: 2px; height: 25px;">
            <div class="gwt-Label GLH-2XVBEO">Latest Contribution</div>
        </div>
        <div
            style="position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 200px; top: 35px; bottom: 5px;">
            <div class="GLH-2XVBDO" style="overflow: auto; position: relative;">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div class="GLH-2XVBCO" style="position: relative;">
                        <div aria-hidden="true"
                            style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div
                            style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 45px;">
                            <div class="GLH-2XVBPO"
                                style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                                <div aria-hidden="true"
                                    style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div
                                    style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 20px;">
                                    <div
                                        style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"
                                        class="gwt-Label GLH-2XVBAP">Argentina</div>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                    style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 25px; width: 200px; height: 20px;">
                                    <div
                                        style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"
                                        class="gwt-Label GLH-2XVBOO">Test Two</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 55px; right: 0px; height: 45px;">
                            <div class="GLH-2XVBPO"
                                style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                                <div aria-hidden="true"
                                    style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div
                                    style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 20px;">
                                    <div
                                        style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"
                                        class="gwt-Label GLH-2XVBAP">General Audience</div>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                    style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 25px; width: 200px; height: 20px;">
                                    <div
                                        style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"
                                        class="gwt-Label GLH-2XVBOO">Test Two</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apologies about the nested divs.  It is GWT-generated HTML code.

Comment: Removing `overflow:auto;` from the `<div classs="GLH-2XVBDO"` (/body/div/div[2]/div) fixes the problem for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `.GLH-2XVBCO` needs a defined height.

So this:

`<div class="GLH-2XVBCO" style="position: relative;">`

becomes something like

`<div class="GLH-2XVBCO" style="position: relative; height: 50px;">`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this style `style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;"`

from the div

```
<div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;">&nbsp;</div>
```

and then you can see Argentina.

Btw, why are you creating such complicated HTML? You should move your styles to a CSS file and remove all the unwanted styles.

Comment: This one works, too, but unfortunately I can't change this part of the GWT-generated code.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can fix it by disabling some of the "position:relative" styles, specifically the ones in GLH-2XVBDO and GLH-2XVBCO, and the DIV between them, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with all these nested DIVs.